# CSV DATA import to nestable json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

Good evening.

I have a CSV data is shown below.

```
level,label,price
1,menu1,3000
2,menu1_1,5000
2,menu1_2,6000
2,menu1_3,7000
1,menu2,8000
2,menu2_1,5000
3,menu2_1_1,5000
3,menu2_1_2,7000
2,menu2_2,6000
2,menu2_3,7000
1,menu3,9000
1,menu4,10000
```

I want to convert this data into json data as shown below. It is necessary that the recursive form should you write any javascript code I see?

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "label": "menu1",
        "price": "3000",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "label": "menu1_1",
                "price": "5000",
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "label": "menu1_2",
                "price": "6000",
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "label": "menu1_1",
                "price": "7000",
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "label": "menu2",
        "price": "8000",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "label": "menu2_1",
                "price": "5000",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "label": "menu2_1_1",
                        "price": "5000",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 8,
                        "label": "menu2_1_2",
                        "price": "7000",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "label": "menu2_2",
                "price": "6000",
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "label": "menu2_3",
                "price": "7000",
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "label": "menu3",
        "price": "9000",
        "mnu_img": "",
        "index": 46,
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "label": "menu4",
        "price": "10000",
        "mnu_img": "",
        "index": 50,
        "children": []
    }
]
```

However, I have a transformation import a CSV source.
Note url: http://techslides.com/convert-csv-to-json-in-javascript

Thanks for your answer. but little problem is shown below.
[image]

i don't need `array[0]` please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I parse the csv data to js objects:

```
var array = data.split("\n").map(function(row, index) { 
  var arr = row.split(",")
  return {
    id: index+1,
    level: +arr[0],
    label: arr[1],
    price: arr[2],
    children: []
  }
})
```

Then I add a level 0, so that everything has a parent:

```
array.unshift({ level: 0, children: [] })
var parents = array.slice(0,1)
```

I loop over the data, comparing the level parameter to the previous one. I also keep the parents in a stack, with this level 0 parent at the bottom.

```
for(var i=1; i<array.length; i++) {
  var prev = array[i-1]
  var obj = array[i]
  var p = parents[parents.length-1]
  if(obj.level > prev.level) {
    parents.push(prev)
    p = prev
  } else if (obj.level < prev.level) {
    do {
      p = parents.pop()
    } while(obj.level < p.level)
    p = parents[parents.length-1]
  }
  p.children.push(obj)
}
```

Finally I read out the result

```
var result = parents[0].children
console.log(result)
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/zexiyigili/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Oh That's my answer to @OLLiM question. Perfect.

`var array = data.split (/ \ r \ n /). map (function (row, index) {`

Here is the code the way the subject line on the first line should go to zero line is I'd love if you want to ignore and put? First, because of the subject line csv line.