# Are My Data Better Suited To A CSV Import, Rather Than a JSON Import?

Tags: json, mongoimport

I am trying to force myself to use mongoDB, using the excuse of the "convenience" of it being able to accept JSON data. Of course, it's not as simple as that (it never is!).

At the moment, for this use case, I think I should revert to a traditional CSV import, and possibly a traditional RDBMS (e.g. MariaDB or MySQL). Am I wrong?

I found a possible solution in [CSV DATA import to nestable json data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29387549/8520561), which seems to be a lot of faffing around.

**The problem:**

I am pulling some data from an online database, which returns data in blocks like this (actually it's all on one line, but I have broken it up to improve readability):

```
[
[8,1469734163000,50.84516753,0.00021818,2],
[6,1469734163000,50.80342373,0.00021818,2],
[4,1469734163000,50.33066367,0.00021818,2],
[12,1469734164000,40.31650031,0.00021918,2],
[10,1469734164000,11.36652478,0.00021818,2],
[14,1469734165000,52.03905845,0.00021918,2],
[16,1469734168000,57.32,0.00021918,2]
]
```

According to the command `python -mjson.tool` this is valid JSON.

But this command barfs

```
mongoimport --jsonArray --db=bitfinexLendingHistory --collection=fUSD --file=test.json
```

with

```
2019-12-31T12:23:42.934+0100    connected to: localhost
2019-12-31T12:23:42.935+0100    Failed: error unmarshaling bytes on document #3: JSON decoder out of sync - data changing underfoot?
2019-12-31T12:23:42.935+0100    imported 0 documents
```

The named DB and collection already exist.

```
$ mongo
> use bitfinexLendingHistory
switched to db bitfinexLendingHistory
> db.getCollectionNames()
[ "fUSD" ]
>
```

I realise that, at this stage, I have no <*whatever the mongoDB equivalent of a column header is called in this case*> defined, but I suspect the problem above is independent of that.

Comment: This is an excellent question, one which people miss all the time. If your data is tabular, and is never sent in JSON format, there probably isn't much reason to force it into JSON and store it that way.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - yet the API devs deemed it suitable to emit valid JSON. I suppose it is not an error in itself to emit JSON. One simply has to know how best to use the data. In this case, I suspect CSV or TSV is better. It's certainly easier to convert the JSON above into a traditional SQL INSERT statement and pipe it into the chosen database table.

Comment: Most API devs don't think twice - they just use JSON because they don't know any better. It certainly has it's uses. It's great for structured messages.

Answer (score 0):

By wrapping by data above in the way as shown below, I managed to get the data imported.

```
{
"arf":
[
    [8,1469734163000,50.84516753,0.00021818,2],
    [6,1469734163000,50.80342373,0.00021818,2],
    [4,1469734163000,50.33066367,0.00021818,2],
    [12,1469734164000,40.31650031,0.00021918,2],
    [10,1469734164000,11.36652478,0.00021818,2],
    [14,1469734165000,52.03905845,0.00021918,2],
    [16,1469734168000,57.32,0.00021918,2]
]
}
```

Next step is to determine if that is what I want, and if so, work out how to query it.